# Generic system for inferring the type of class required from given parameter type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a basic architecture for 'orders' in my game - each order has a basic data type and an 'order processor' which performs some action based on the given data. For example 'move to this point.'

I'd like to have a tidy system where I can simply pass in order data and the correct order processor will kick in, in such a way that I can easily add new OrderData/OrderProcessor classes without modifying other classes or messing around with enums or casting, so it seems like generics are the way to go.

This is the current code I have. I'm drawing a blank for how to draw a connection in the 'OrderService' class between the correct 'OrderProcessor' and 'IOrderData' pairs. See inside the `OrderService<T>` class for more information:

```
public interface IOrderData
{
}

// an order processor reads data from an IOrderData object until the data object says stop
public abstract class OrderProcessor<T> where T : IOrderData
{
    protected T m_currentData;

    public virtual void Start(T data)
    {
        m_currentData = data;
    }
}

////////////////////////

public class MoveOrderData : IOrderData
{
    public Vector3 Destination { get; private set; }
}

public class MoveOrderProcessor : OrderProcessor<MoveOrderData>
{
    public override void Start(MoveOrderData data)
    {
        base.Start(data);
    }
}

////////////////////////

public class OrderService<T> where T : IOrderData
{
    private Dictionary<System.Type, OrderProcessor<T>> m_processors = new Dictionary<System.Type, OrderProcessor<T>>();
    private OrderProcessor<T> m_currentProcessor;

    public void GiveOrder(IOrderData data)
    {
        // this is the main problem: I'm not sure how to say "the given data is type 'MoveOrderData' so find out which 
        // OrderProcessor class handles those and pass it in". A simple switch statement and cast would suffice here 
        // but I'd like to automate the process
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need generics here? What about just having base class for order data and processor?

Comment: Can you not have each order handle the processing for itself - why do you need a OrderProcessor for a particular order type ?

Comment: How would I then say in OrderService "I've received an object of type MoveOrderData, pass this in to the MoveOrderProcessor and not the AttackOrderProcessor, JumpOrderProcessor, etc?

Comment: What i'm saying is why not combine the two things (the data and the processing) into one entity ?

Comment: @auburg I would like to split up the data class and the processing class. Ideally in the future I'll be passing in structs for the data to avoid allocations, or switch the data 'mid stream' without replacing the entire processing object. My comment was in response to the previous comment there

Comment: can´t you just use the generic parameter within `GiveOrder`: `public void GiveOrder(T data) ...` Btw.: your `m_CurrentMember` within `OrderProcessor<T>` should surely be of type `T`.

Comment: Well you could always come up with your own convention... Based on the order data type ("MoveOrderData") invoke the method on the ("MoveOrderProcessor") via reflection. This could by an XY problem in the first place

Comment: @HimBromBeere true, I can, but I still need to find the correct OrderProcessor type to pass the data into now.

Comment: @EmmetOT Ah, I see. In this case there´s no way to achieve that, because generics are a **compile-time**-feature, whereas you provide the actual type at **runtime**. You will use un-generic base-interface probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution here can be a making an `OrderService` class non-generic, because it can handle a different types of orders/order processors (according to comments). Then maintain a `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`, which wraps `Action<object>` to call `Start` method from `OrderProcessor<T>`.

I've extended the original code a little bit to show how it can work

```cs
public interface IOrderData
{
}

public class MoveOrderData : IOrderData
{
    public Vector3 Destination { get; private set; }
}

public class AttackOrderData : IOrderData
{
}

public abstract class OrderProcessor<T> where T : IOrderData
{
    protected T CurrentData { get; set; }

    public virtual void Start(T data)
    {
        CurrentData = data;
    }
}

public class MoveOrderProcessor : OrderProcessor<MoveOrderData>
{
}

public class AttackOrderProcessor : OrderProcessor<AttackOrderData>
{
}

public class OrderService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> m_processors = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    public OrderService()
    {
        AddProcessor(new MoveOrderProcessor());
        AddProcessor(new AttackOrderProcessor());
    }

    private void AddProcessor<T>(OrderProcessor<T> processor) where T : IOrderData
    {
        var action = (Action<T>)processor.Start;
        m_processors.Add(typeof(T), obj => action((T)obj));
    }

    public void GiveOrder(IOrderData data)
    {
        var action = m_processors[data.GetType()];
        action?.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

It causes a downcasting `obj => action((T)obj)`, but it shouldn't be a problem, since your data is constrained to `IOrderData` interface. Example of the usage

```cs
var service = new OrderService();
service.GiveOrder(new MoveOrderData());
service.GiveOrder(new AttackOrderData());
```